# Send email after order is canceled

Tags: magento-1, event-observer, email, transactional-mail

I am trying to send an email when order is canceled. I followed this tutorial:

> http://www.atwix.com/magento/emails-for-custom-events/

Here is my code i need help setting it up becouse now it is not working:

Local.xml:

> 1.0.0

```
<global>
    <models>
        <cancelemail>
            <class>Ylli_Cancelemail_Model</class>
        </cancelemail>
    </models>
    <events>
        <sales_order_save_commit_after>
            <observers>
                <Ylli_Cancelemail_Model_Observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Ylli_Cancelemail_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>invoicedStatusChange</method>
                </Ylli_Cancelemail_Model_Observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_save_commit_after>
    </events>
    <template>
        <email>
            <custom_order_tpl module="Ylli_Cancelemail">
                <label>Status Mail Invoice</label>
                <file>statusmail_canceled.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </custom_order_tpl>
        </email>
    </template>
</global>
```

Observer.php

```
class Ylli_Cancelemail_Model_Observer {
    public function invoicedStatusChange($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        var_dump($order);
        Mage::log('worked', null, 'cancelemail.log');
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            $this->_sendStatusMail($order);
    }


private  function _sendStatusMail($order)
{
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_tpl');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was holded');

    // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
    $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

    $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
    $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
}
```

Any help is appreciated. thanks in advace

Comment: can you please tell is event is fire ya email is nit fired

Comment: No the event is not fired, i have tried to make a log file but it does not create it. so i think it is an event problem. can you give me some debugging help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I want to have a cms page where I will list all products that have special_offer dropdown attribute with yes value. I found something [here](http://inchoo.net/magento/featured-products-on-magento-frontpage-tutorial/Ylii,) but this is work only with the Yes/No attribute. I need to use dropdown attribute because I want to use this attribute in the layered navigation too.

So how I can display dropdown special_offer attribute where options are Yes and No?

This is the public function where the products are sorted:

```
public function getFeaturedProducts()
{
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $read = $resource->getConnection('catalog_read');
    $productEntityIntTable = (string) Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix() . 'catalog_product_entity_int';
    $eavAttributeTable = $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute');
    $categoryProductTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product');

    $select = $read->select()
        ->distinct(true)
        ->from(array('cp'=>$categoryProductTable), 'product_id')
        ->join(array('pei'=>$productEntityIntTable), 'pei.entity_id=cp.product_id', array())
        ->joinNatural(array('ea'=>$eavAttributeTable))
        ->where('pei.value=1')
        ->where('ea.attribute_code="special_offer"');

    $res = $read->fetchAll($select);

    return $res;
}
```

There issue with `fetch data from event`.you  can get your passing `event data` using `$observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')` for getting the data of event data.

According magento,**_save_commit_after event on `dispatch` on below code  at class Mage_Core_Model_Abstract

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_commit_after', $this->_getEventData());
```

According to this event it pass data using `$this->_getEventData()` for getting data you need to use `$observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')` at Observer file.

For getting old data  use `getOrigData()`

**Example**:

```
$Olddata= $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')->getOrigData()
```

and  for getting current change  data `getData()`

**Example:**

```
$new_data = $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')->getData();
```

This is provide current change data in array format;

```
public function invoicedStatusChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $original_data = $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')->getOrigData();
    $new_data = $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')->getData();
    Mage::log($original_data);
    Mage::log($new_data);
    if (($original_data['state'] !== $new_data['state']) && ($new_data['state'] == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)) {
        Mage::log('Yes+cancel');
        /**
        * This is where you can place your process code
        */
    }
}
```

**Previous data: print in log file:**

```
2015-01-18T12:48:31+00:00 DEBUG (7):
 Array
(
    [entity_id] => 192 //order id
    [state] => new
    [status] => pending
...
[subtotal_incl_tax] => 372.3800
    ....
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
)
```

**Current change data:**

```
2015-01-18T12:48:31+00:00 DEBUG (7):
Array
(
    [entity_id] => 192 //order id
    [state] => canceled
    [status] => canceled

    ...
    [subtotal_incl_tax] => 372.3800
    .......
    [base_shipping_hidden_tax_amount] => 0.0000
)
```

---

## Full Module:

> app\code\local\Ylli\Cancelemail\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Ylli_Cancelemail>
                <version>0.1.0</version>
            </Ylli_Cancelemail>
        </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <cancelemail>
                <class>Ylli_Cancelemail_Helper</class>
            </cancelemail>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <cancelemail>
                <class>Ylli_Cancelemail_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>cancelemail_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </cancelemail>
        </models>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after> <!-- identifier of the event we want to catch -->
                <observers>
                    <sales_order_save_commit_after_handler> <!-- identifier of the event handler -->
                        <type>model</type> <!-- class method call type; valid are model, object and singleton -->
                        <class>cancelemail/observer</class> <!-- observers class alias -->
                        <method>invoicedStatusChange</method>  <!-- observer's method to be called -->
                        <args></args> <!-- additional arguments passed to observer -->
                    </sales_order_save_commit_after_handler>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

> Ylli\Cancelemail\Model\Observer.php

```
<?php
class Ylli_Cancelemail_Model_Observer
{
    public function invoicedStatusChange(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $original_data = $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')->getOrigData();
        $new_data = $observer->getEvent()->getData('data_object')->getData();
        Mage::log($original_data);
        Mage::log($new_data);
        if (($original_data['state'] !== $new_data['state']) && ($new_data['state'] == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)) {
            Mage::log('Yes+cancel');
            /**
            * This is where you can place your process code
            */
        }
    }
}
```

> app/code/local/Ylli/Cancelemail/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Ylli_Cancelemail_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{
}
```

> app/etc/modules/Ylli_Cancelemail.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Ylli_Cancelemail>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <active>true</active>
        </Ylli_Cancelemail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for the code, when i try it in localhost it works great but when i try it on my live site it does not work, the event is not fired at all.

Comment: it may be your live system cache issue

Comment: I tried flushing all cache and reindexing but nothing worksn any other sugestion?

Comment: no ,i have test it on live server , it is worked perfectly

Comment: Can you please send me the module to make a comparison with my module.

Comment: please give me time ,  i will put the modules...

Comment: How much time do you need ?

Comment: your email adress?

Comment: Hi @AmitBera i try this but it's not working for my live site

Comment: Hi @AmitBera, I followed the same atwix tutorial but i'm trying to do something a bit different. Do you think you could help me out?  Thanks in advance.  http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108420/when-a-product-is-disabled-through-admin-send-a-notification-email