# When a product is disabled through admin send a notification email

Tags: product, magento-enterprise, event-observer, ee-1.13, status

Hooking into the event/observer methods already created I could build an email that would send when the status was update to `'status' => 2` correct? After the event has taken place.

I believe I would use this event?

```
<catalog_product_status_update>
    <observers>
        <sales_quote>
            <class>sales/observer</class>
            <method>catalogProductStatusUpdate</method>
        </sales_quote>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_status_update>
```

My observer:

```
class Namespace_Custmail_Model_Observer
{
    public function invoicedStatusChange($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        $orderStatus = $order->getStatus();
        if ($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_CANCELED)
            $this->_sendStatusMail($order);
    }

    private  function _sendStatusMail($order)
    {
        $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_tpl');
        $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Your order was holded');

        // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
        $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
        $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

        $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
        $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

        $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();
        $emailTemplateVariables['order_id'] = $order->getIncrementId();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
        $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
        $emailTemplate->send($order->getCustomerEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
    }
}
```

Basically, anytime a product is disabled send an email. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're right on the event `catalog_product_status_update` here's how you could do create a new method in your observer to implement the email notification system:

```
public function catalogProductStatusUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $status = $observer->getEvent()->getStatus();
    if ($status == Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED) {
        return $this;
    }
    $productId  = $observer->getEvent()->getProductId();
    $storeId  = $observer->getEvent()->getStoreId();
    $this->_sendProductStatusMail($productId, $storeId);
}

private  function _sendProductStatusMail($productId, $storeId)
{
    $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

    $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_product_tpl');
    $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('The product was disabled');

    // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
    $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
    $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

    $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
    $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);

    $emailTemplateVariables['product_id'] = $productId;
    $emailTemplateVariables['store_id'] = $storeId;
    $emailTemplate->send($salesData['email'], $salesData['name'], $emailTemplateVariables);
}
```

Please note that you will have to create a **custom_product_tpl** email template and probably modify the `_sendProductStatusMail` method to fit your needs.